# mapbox - anyone how to remove leading zero in a mapbox text field?

Tags: mapbox

mapbox - anyone how to remove leading zero in a mapbox text field? I'm doing this in mapbox layer under their Styles page.

I'm looking at their expressions documentation but didn't find any plausible way:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you totally can, just gotta [slice](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#slice) it, much like JavaScript slice, so in your case:

```
["slice", 1] // returns all characters after the first
```

Remember, you would have to combine this with a `getter` to have a string to operate on, however.